# 'source' command definition in virtualenvironment connection establishment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have been working on Django project from few weeks and everytime I run the server, or make migrations or migrate all the packages are seperated from system directory to virtualenvironment.

I execute the below command to kickstart virtualenvironment

```
$source venv/bin/activate
```

What does 'source' signify in the above command ?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, it sets your path environment variables so it knows to check for installed packages in your virtual environment directory, so you don't have to do things like install them in a directory which you don't have (sudo) access.

i.e. you can do `pip install` without `sudo` and still have your `python` know where to find that package.

For more details on the source command itself, see [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)